# How to set error messages from Axios response with Typescript and Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js

I have a Next.js app that makes an API call for a register form. When there are server side validation errors I get a response back like this:

```
{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"email":["The email has already been taken."],"password":["The password must be at least 8 characters."]}}
```

In my code I would like to show the `email` and `password` errors to the user if they are present. Currently my code is:

```
const RegisterPage: NextPageWithLayout = () => {

  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [setEmailError, emailError] = useState<string | null>(null)
  const [setPasswordError, passwordError] = useState<string | null>(null)

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (isSubmitting) return;
    setIsSubmitting(true);
    try {
      // handle success
    } catch (err){
      // @ts-ignore
      const errors = err?.response?.data?.errors;
      if(errors instanceof Object){
        setEmailError(errors['email']) // this does not work
        setPasswordError(errors['password'] || null) // this does not work
      }

      setIsSubmitting(false);
    }
  };
```

However this code does not work. My IDE shows a couple errors on the line for setting email and password errors:

```
TS2349: This expression is not callable.   
   Type 'String' has no call signatures.
TS2721: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null'.
```

How can I set the `emailError` and `passwordError` variables so I can display the error messages to the user if they are present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `useState`, Setter method is the second argument not the first.

```
const [emailError, setEmailError  ] = useState<string | null>(null)
const [passwordError, setPasswordError] = useState<string | null>(null)
```

add a type to errors and check if error is null or not

```
  const errors: {email?: string, password?: string} = err?.response?.data?.errors;
  if(errors){
    setEmailError(errors?.email || null)  
    setPasswordError(errors?.password || null)  
  }
```